# How to change (bug-fix) the Release notes

Tags: documentation, release, bug-tracking, changelog

Today I found that an important bug had been fixed in a version that was already released. The Release notes (`changes.txt`) we shipped along with this version (say 3.9.1) did not contain this change.

From your experience: Where is the best place to integrate the change?

- the 3.9.1 section (which will probably not being read in the next release)
- the 3.9.2 section (pretending the bug was fixed only now)
- Are there other and probably better options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the bug is in the documentation (the release notes file of version 3.9.1), you could simply fix it there. Add an entry to the new release notes (3.9.2) that references this issue in the documentation of the last release (with any information relevant to your users).

Comment: Ok, seems to be the third option ;-)